# How to load a particular page when the website opens in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know it might be insanely easy but being new to angular I do not understand how to load a particular template as soon as the website is opened.
I have a template:

```
 <script type= "text/ng-template" id="home.html" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
 <h2 style="text-align: center;" >Welcome to the Admin Tools!</h2>
   </script>
```

Which is linked to the following button on the nav bar:

```
   <li><a href='#/home'><span>Home</span></a></li>
```

How can I allow the website to load this particular template as soon as the URL of the website is entered
Angular:

```
 myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider, $routeParams) {
$routeProvider.when('/home', {
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl'
})
 }]);
```

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Comment: I have routing added to this page as well I will edit the code to show the route. But How do I get it to load when the user enters the site

Comment: Have your really read this tutorial? templateUrl param is all you need. Just use proper path to html template and make it as it is in tut.

Comment: Yes but I have the template URL at the moment if I click home, it shows me the template, but I want index.html#/home to load when the user tries to load /index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$routeProvider` service. The method called `otherwise` can be used to set the route definition that will be used on route change when no other route definition is matched.

[Here's](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) the documentation for the same. Also, they have elaborated this with an example [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example).

Comment: Yes I have accepted it now, It had time limit on it, hence I couldnt do it straight away

Comment: You can also use `.when('/', options)`, which is possibly better practise `otherwise` should redirect to a 'proper' page (or a "whoops" style pseudo 404).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/tpl.html">
       Content of the template.
</script>

<a ng-click="currentTpl='/tpl.html'" id="tpl-link">Load inlined template</a>
<div id="tpl-content" ng-include src="currentTpl"></div>
```

Comment: I think angular.route may be a better choice

Comment: @user3756848 oh sorry, I failed to understand your question, otherwise is right.